# View/Edit Work Items and Deny Access to Source Code in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

How can I set up TFS 2010 permissions in such a way that only developers can access Source Control, but other groups can view or edit Work Items, all within the same Team Project?

I need to have my business analysts and QA testers be able to update user story states, assignees, etc. within an Iteration, but deny them access to the source code for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is partially correct. This is how you set permissions within your source control tree. That answer also assumes that every single file and folder in your source control tree has the "Inherit Security Settings" box checked. Permissions within TFS 2010 source control can be much more granular than that.

Permissions for work items are handled at a work item "Area" level. Since Areas are per-team-project work item permissions are also per-team-project.

In Team Explorer right click on your Team Project -> Team Project Settings -> Areas and Iterations. This is where you can setup new Area \ Iterations. There is also a "Security" button at the bottom of the window that will pop the security settings for ***the selected area node.*** You can set these permissions very granularly as well... Area nodes always inherit security from their parent node, but can have individual permissions set as well.

Comment: Will this enable me to allow access to the Work Items, but deny access to the Source Control? It appears to be an all-or-nothing setting.

Comment: Mark, Yes. You can grant one set of users access to edit workitems under a specific area path... and you can grant your other set of users access to files, folders, branches, etc in source control. The permissions for source control and work items are completely unrelated. 

Out-of-the-box TFS lets everyone in the Contributor security group access both source control and work items. For your purposes the out-of-the-box security setup won't work. You could create separate groups for source control and work item access.

Comment: Jesus this tfs and its weird permissions, spent around 1 hour to figure this out XD

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution!

I finally managed to totally hide source code from specific group of users (although I allow them to see work items) by setting **"Edit collection-level information=>Not Set"** on **"Project Collection Valid Users"** in **"DefaultCollection Groups"**.
Of course I had to manually deny every permission on the root ($) of source code but I suppose this could work for any path you like.
After that I created areas and allowed on this group specific areas and everything goes perfect!

For some reason **"Edit collection-level information"** was set to allow and strangely, this prevented from hiding the source code!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Open **Source Control Explorer**.
3. Navigate to your Projects Root Branch (same name as the Project).
4. Right Click and Select **Properties...**
5. Click the **Security** Tab.

In there you can control all the permissions you like. Denying `Read` permissions will stop the User/Group/TFS Group from been able to see you Source (IIRC, I'm a Collection Admin and it's hard to test).

Comment: This appears to block the user from the *entire* Team Project, not just the Source Control section. I've revised my question to clarify my goal. Thanks!

Comment: How about Removing Read on the Source Code Folder(s) under the the Root node in Source Control Explorer?

Comment: Denying read indeed prevent users from seeing the contents but it still allows to see the full tree of your source code (files and folders)! I am trying to accomplish the same thing with Mark, but with no success! I wonder, is it possible?

Comment: @GeorgeMavritsakis I'm pretty sure I have done this successfully for a third party we work with. By denying read and granting read to a TFS Group worked... although I'll double check tomorrow :)